# how to get model class item in firestore paging adapter?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I want to get position of an item by its value like model.getId()

I'm using firestore paging adapter

i know to get the position of a item by its value in normal adapter like below

```
private int getAdapterItemPosition(long id)
{
    for (int position=0; position<mListAdapter.getCount(); position++)
        if (mListAdapter.get(position).getId() == id)
            return position;
    return 0;
}
```

But how I achieve this in firestore paging adapter ???

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you trying to achieve but you can use `getCurrentList()` method with your adapter to get the list of current paged list.

That's how your existing code will look like

```
    private int getAdapterItemPosition(long id) {

        List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = mListAdapter.getCurrentList();

        for(int i = 0; i < documentSnapshotList.size(); i++) {

            ModelClass model  = documentSnapshotList.get(i).toObject(ModelClass.class);

            if(model.getId() == id) {

                return i;
            }

        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Change the `ModelClass` accordingly.

Comment: @BeginnerDev if you think it helped you you can mark this answer as accepted :)